# JavaScript SyntaxError is just a string, not an object?

Tags: javascript, error-handling, syntax-error

My application is dynamically loading scripts, so I set a `window.onerror` handler to report syntax errors that prevent the scripts loading, as follows:

```
window.onerror = function(error) {
  alert("ERROR: " + error.message + ": " + error.stack);
};
```

What I get when I load a script is an alert saying `ERROR: undefined: undefined`. When I change it to display the value and type of `error`:

```
window.onerror = function(error) {
  alert("ERROR: " + typeof(error) + ": " + error);
};
```

what I get is `ERROR: string: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`. This happens on both Firefox and Chrome.

According to the docs, SyntaxError is supposed to be an Error object with `message` and `stack` and other properties. I'd really like to know where the error occurred, and not just what it is! Am I doing something wrong here? Is there any way I can get more information about the error?

Comment: [typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) is an operator, not a function.

Comment: You should try adding the handler with `.addEventHandler()` instead of setting it up via the "onerror" property. For historical reasons, those two ways of doing things result in different behavior.

Comment: @mykaf: I know, and parentheses are legal around the expression the operator applies to. It's not incorrect, it's my personal preference. Nit-picking is not useful and doesn't even try to answer the question.

Comment: @Pointy: I presume you meant ``.addEventListener()``, which indeed gives me an object. The object contains lineno and colno as in the answer below, but no source file name. Dumping the object as JSON just gives ``{"isTrusted": "true"}``and the docs for ErrorEvent are incomplete. So thanks for your help, but I'm going with the answer below.

Comment: @user1636349 ohj yes, wow I must have been low on caffeine :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error event has multiple parameters. The first is the event name, which is a string.

```js
onerror = (event, source, lineno, colno, error) => {};
```

[Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/error_event)